# How can I include value "zero" in uniques count in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, count

So my task is to have a function count(X) that receives an arrangement 'X' filled with non-negative values and outputs a different arrangement of dimensions 'max + 1' which includes the frequency of each value within 'X'.

So far I have this:

```
  def count(X):

  # here I obtain the maximum value within X

      maxi = np.max(X)

  # then I calculate the needed value of the output arrangement

      outsize = np.size(X)+1

  # here I generate a zeroes arrangement with the needed size to save the answers
  counts = np.zeros((1,outsize))

  # Now here is where I find the issue when I try to iterate for each value within X
  for num in X:
     counts= np.unique(X, return_counts=True) 

    # the output should be an arrangement of size max+1 which contains the occurrences of a given value
    # in X when X=0, X=1...etc
      
      return counts
```

Say i.e. if I call

```
print(counts(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6])))
```

The output should be

```
[0. 1. 1. 3. 0. 2. 1.]
```

however what I'm getting is

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), array([1, 1, 3, 2, 1]))
```

I looked through the documentation, but can't seem to find a specific piece of code to include "0", and also I don't know how to delete the first array from the output (the one that lists all the possible values) Any Ideas? Much appreciated

Comment: Isn't what you're trying to do just [`numpy.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)?

Comment: It Actually Is. I just replaced counts= np.unique(X, return_counts=True) with np.bincount(X) and the output is exactly what was asked initially. 
Thank you very much. The question is solved.

Comment: Also, that loop doesn't make sense. You're not using `nums` at all, and you're unconditionally returning on the first iteration.

Comment: If you're going to use `numpy.bincount`, you can get rid of your whole `count` function. You don't need any of it - `numpy.bincount` does the job directly.